# error when using tailwind safelist with pattern in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

I get an error with the tailwind safelist as soon as I use a pattern. I have no idea what it could be

in ./src/assets/tailwind.css

```
TypeError: t.test is not a function
     at Array.some (<anonymous>)


  @ ./src/main.js 19:0-31
  @ multi ./src/main.js
```

```
purge: {
     content: ['./src/**/*.html','./src/**/*.vue'],
     safelist: [
       'bg-blue-500',
       'text center',
       'hover:opacity-100',
       'lg:text-right',
       'duration-1250',
       'duration-1000',
       'duration-200',
       'duration-100',
       'duration-0',
       'opacity-0',
       'opacity-50',
       'opacity-100',
        {
          pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)/,
        },
        {
          pattern: /opacity-/,
        },
     ]
   },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `purge` key, I would assume you are using Tailwind v2. The `pattern` object syntax you are using seems to be for [Tailwind v3's `safelist` option](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions).

If we look [at the documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#safelisting-specific-classes), `safelist` is only shown to support string members:

> ```js
> // tailwind.config.js
> module.exports = {
>   purge: {
>     content: ['./src/**/*.html'],
>     safelist: [
>       'bg-blue-500',
>       'text-center',
>       'hover:opacity-100',
>       // ...
>       'lg:text-right',
>     ]
>   },
>   // ...
> }
> ```

Tailwind v2 uses [PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/) [under the hood](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/ee87fed11376b2d23778ca2cb8ea99108416a734/src/lib/purgeUnusedStyles.js#L188-L220). We can see that it passes `safelist` to the options to PurgeCSS after calling `standardizeSafelist`:

```js
safelist: standardizeSafelist(purgeOptions.safelist),
```

Looking [at the documentation for `standardizeSafelist`](https://purgecss.com/api-reference/purgecss.standardizesafelist.html#standardizesafelist-function), we see that the argument type is [`userDefinedSafelist`](https://purgecss.com/api-reference/purgecss.userdefinedsafelist.html):

```
export declare function standardizeSafelist(userDefinedSafelist?: UserDefinedSafelist): Required<ComplexSafelist>;
```

Which in itself can be a [`StringRegExpArray`](https://purgecss.com/api-reference/purgecss.stringregexparray.html):

```
export declare type UserDefinedSafelist = StringRegExpArray | ComplexSafelist;
```

If we take a look at `StringRegExpArray`:

```
export declare type StringRegExpArray = Array<RegExp | string>;
```

As the name suggests, it can be an array of [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [regular expression (`RegExp`) objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). So we can use regular expression objects in the array directly, so your `purge` configuration should look like:

```js
purge: {
  content: ['./src/**/*.html','./src/**/*.vue'],
  safelist: [
    'bg-blue-500',
    'text center',
    'hover:opacity-100',
    'lg:text-right',
    'duration-1250',
    'duration-1000',
    'duration-200',
    'duration-100',
    'duration-0',
    'opacity-0',
    'opacity-50',
    'opacity-100',
    /bg-(red|green|blue)-(100|200|300)/,
    /opacity-/,
  ]
},
```

Comment: thanks for your brilliant explanation!